# Add LambdaFunctionAssociation to existing CloudFront distribution with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I want to add LambdaFunctionAssociation to my existing CloudFront which is created manually
[lambdafunctionassociation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-lambdafunctionassociation.html)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This template does that, one key is "versioning" the lambda function.  This template creates a distribution, a function, a bucket and a couple of other things, but if you follow back from the FunctionArn it should help you out.

[Template To Create Distribution With Function](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hounddog22030/ed33bc1935369465a8f783c8ac7cf7bc/raw/d412dfb39209af66f51a8362655d434acd710d29/sleet.template)

Answer (score 0):

key point:

"LambdaFunctionARN" should be the Arn of the Lambda version, not the Lambda function

For example:

```
"LambdaFunctionAssociations": [
    {
         "EventType": "origin-request",
         "IncludeBody": true,
         "LambdaFunctionARN": {
             "Ref": "LambdaVersion"
         }
     }
]
```

pointing to a Version resource :

```
 "LambdaVersion": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Version",
        "Properties": {
           "Description": "v1",
          "FunctionName": {
             "Ref": "MyLambdaFunction"
             }
           }
         }
```